# Filtering using js

Tags: javascript, html

for some reason, every time i try to search or type in a text like `Area15`/`Uptown` or something, it doesn't remove the unrelated ones, did i do something wrong here?

I was trying to make a filter or something, to filter out what's on the table but it doesn't seem to work can anyone help or advice me on what i did wrong? am i lacking something here in my js?

```
<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="search for places." title="Type in a name">

<table id="myTable">
    <tr class="header">
        <th style="width:60%">Town</th>
        <th style="width:40%">Area</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Downtown</td>
        <td>Area15</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Uptown</td>
        <td>Area16</td>
    </tr>
</table>


<script>
    function myFunction() {
    var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
    input = document.getElementById("myInput");
    filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
    table = document.getElementById("myTable");
    tr = table.getElementByTagName("tr");
    for (i=0; i<tr.length; i++){
        td= tr[i].getElementByTagName("td")[0];
        if (td){
            if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexof(filter) >-1) {
                tr[i].style.display = " ";
            } else {
                tr[i}.style.display = "none";}
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: where is the element with id `myInput`

Comment: As I understood you try to filter "Area" column, but, in fact, you apply filter only to "Town" column.

Comment: there i edited it, the input tag didn't show up forgot to add the spacing, and even if i changed othe inserted text to `Uptown` it still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It is because of this line `td= tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];`It is searching only the first `td` inside `tr`.`getElementsByTagName` returns a collection & `getElementsByTagName("td")[0]` is asking to search only in the first `td`, If you chabge it to `getElementsByTagName("td")[1]` it will search only in second column

```js
function myFunction() {
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
        tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input id='myInput' onkeyup="myFunction()">


<table id="myTable">
  <tr class="header">
    <th style="width:60%">Town</th>
    <th style="width:40%">Area</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Downtown</td>
    <td>Area15</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Downtown</td>
    <td>Area16</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Actually you have also fixed a typo - it shows "indexof" and you've put "indexOf" thereby fixing that too.

Comment: @ChrisCousins yes ans also `getElementsByTagName`

Comment: although i did fix the typo, it still doesn't remove the other tr or in this case if i put `Area16` it still doesn't remove/hide the `Area15` one

Comment: @Furvus Another error here `tr[i}.style.display = "none";}` in this line